# Logged in customer with setCustomerAsLoggedIn() logs out automatically after redirect

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, redirect

Freshly created and active user, after redirection to user cabinet logged out instantly:

```
                $this->_session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
                $session = $this->_session;

                $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setEmail($email)
                                                               ->save();
                // ^^^ successfully saves the customer entity

                $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

                // autoconfirm user
                if($customer->getConfirmation()!=null){
                    $customer->setConfirmation(null);
                }
                if($session->isLoggedIn()) {

                    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl().'customer/account/');
                    return;
                }
```

it successfully redirects and shows the user cabinet and 'Log out' link is active, but if I open the magento front page in other tab of same browser it becomes clearly that customer is not logged in.
Where to debug ?
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I am trying to login freshly created customer without password. Password attribute set to 'required'=>false in customer entity, via install script.

**UPDATE 2**

I was also forgot to $customer->save(); after $customer->setConfirmation(null); it is mandatory

Comment: I assume this is a snippet and that $session is set using $session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );  ?

Comment: yes, this is Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' ); session object, edited snipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual customer login works similarly to your code but that function sets the website ID, make sure you are doing this.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->setEmail($email)->save();

$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

Comment: may i ask you if $session->login() method is necessary for user to set logged in? thanks!

Comment: That's the way I have seen it in the past.  However, if you look at the login function, it is doing something very similar to what you are doing.   I did notice one difference.  I update my answer to that difference.

Answer (score 0):

In **System > Configuration > General > Web > Session Cookie Management**
set **Cookie Path** as **/**

This makes your script and magento use same frontend cookie.